# How to set media query only when elements stack

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have two divs in a row:

```
<div id='div1' class="col-md-3" style="float:right;">
</div>
<div id='div2' class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
</div>
```

When the window is large enough, the two divs sit side-by-side
However, when the window width is reduced, 'div1' stacks on top of 'div2'. 
'div2' has `margin-left:5%;` How can I set the same for div2 but *only* when it is stacked on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They stack because of how bootstrap's columns work. The classes `col-md-3` and `col-md-9` means that when the screen size hits `992px` (according to the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)), your divs will take up 3 and 9 columns (out of twelve total) respectively. This is how bootstrap's grid system was designed to work. If the screen width is smaller than that, then they will both take up the full width of the screen. Your media query should look something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) { <your_css> }
```

Comment: thanks for adding the docs link, that specific number is what I couldn't find!